# Wordpress site opening malware popups "onclkds.com" on mobile site

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, malware

I made website on **Wordpress**,
till today it was working fine but now when I open my website on mobile it open popups of *onclkds.com*, I have searched for the solution and many of the forums have suggested that it is issue related to browser extensions.

But as I totally researched on it, may be its because of some free plugins which is dynamically creating this dynamic popups. but i tried to deactivate this plugins nothing worked for me because it already added the code to my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already had this problem, I managed to clean one of my website for this tutorial:
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-remove-the-http-onclkds-com-ad-from-my-WordPress-website

Comment: Please copy the content, format it and post it here. Sometimes the links may not be accesible

Comment: Thanks buddy that solved my problem in seconds. Thank you very much.